# What determines the valency of predicates?

Tags: syntax, verbs, valency

[image]

According to this example, *arrive* takes only one subject valent.

Can somebody specializes in syntax help me apprehend this notion of valence? Specifically, what factors are used to determine the valence of predicates?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is still not clear, because of different possible meanings for "determine". Are you asking what are the factors in a language (or in language in general) which cause a particular predicate to have a particular valence? Or are you asking about how grammarians analysing a language decide what valence the predicates actually have?

Answer (score 3):

This tree(8a) shown is a mistake.  The author did it on purpose to show that we can't draw like that, **I suppose**.

8a shows that "arrive" has two dependency, one is "Fred" and the other is "Tom".  However, the correct thing to do is that "arrive" *has just one dependency* and it is **"Fred and Tom"** as a whole.

Then "arrive" has just one dependency and it has just one valency.

I hope it can make sense to you.

Comment: Hmm I might misunderstand your question..... Sorry